# Apply attribute on all enum based on version in asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have WEB api which is in asp.net core with the versioning like (V1,V2 & V3).
The url like below for that

> http://localhost:4000/v1/getUsers
>
> http://localhost:4000/v2/getUsers
>
> http://localhost:4000/v3/getUsers

I applied `StringEnumConverter` in the startup class, in this way all the `enum` gives the response into `string`. That was handled globally.

Now the problem was we need `enum` as `integer` value in v1 version only.

So I have done Rnd on search engine and getting solution like we can use a `[JsonConverter(typeof(ForceDefaultConverter))]`.

> https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/11/12/override-json-net-serialization-settings-back-to-default/

I used it and it works in that way as expected.

```
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public enum ErrorCode
    {
        NotFound = 1,
        NotImplemented = 2
    }

    public class ForceDefaultConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanRead => false;
        public override bool CanWrite => false;

        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Now, the problem is that I need to use `ForceDefaultConverter` only in case of version V1 not in V2 and V3. Can we handle this globally. I need to apply `ForceDefaultConverter` attribute on every `enum` when Path contains V1. Can we handle this version wise in startup class.

Comment: Let me know if anyone having idea